# Match two Calendar lists in Scala

Tags: list, scala, functional-programming

I am starting with Scala and currently I am trying to write an algorithm that receives two lists with Calendar times and it has to select the matching times.

For example, the first list has the following values (for the sake of simplicity I will only put the times):

[12:00, 12:50, 13:40, 14:30, 15:20, 16:10, 17:00, 17:50, 18:40]

The second list has the following values:

[13:20, 13:40, 14:30, 15:20, 16:10, 16:30]

I want to get a list with the following values:

[13:40, 14:30, 15:20, 16:10]

This values represent every 50 minute interval that matches the first and the second list.

I could use an iterative method to solve this problem. I would only have to run through the two lists and see if the values matched my needs but it wouldn't be very functional and I am trying to write good Scala code. However, I can't come with an idea to solve this problem functionally.

Can anyone help me with this problem, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `intersect` function on `List`. It computes the multiset intersection of the lists. All elements that exists in both lists will be added to the resulting list.

```
val list1 = List("12:00", "12:50", "13:40", "14:30", "15:20",
                 "16:10", "17:00", "17:50", "18:40")

val list2 = List("13:20", "13:40", "14:30", "15:20", "16:10", "16:30")

val matched = list1.intersect(list2) // Gives List(13:40, 14:30, 15:20, 16:10)
```